# Flip and negate a coordinate point in java?

Tags: java, class, object, methods, point

How would you take a point object and flip the coordinates and switch their signs? If you wanted to add a method called flip to the code below:

```
    public class Point {
    private int x;
    private int y;

    // flip method goes here

}
```

I've tried things like:

```
    public class flip(){
    x = 0-x;
    y = 0-y;
    Point p = new Point(y,x);
}
```

But it's not working. (81,21) and I only get (-81,-21). It doesn't flip it. But method can't take any parameters, if that's even relevant. Thanks.

Comment: Your flip code makes no sense at all and is obviously not code you've actually tried. It's a method that returns a class? Really?? Please only post ***real*** code attempts, not sort-of kind-of code attempts. Also, if you're going to flip a point, you need to input the line about which the flip will occur. You can rotate about a point, but not flip. This may be either the X or Y axis, but actually it could theoretically be ***any*** line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to flip the coordinates in place (so calling `p.flip()` modifies `Point p`, then this should work:

```
public class Point {
    private int x;
    private int y;

    public void flip() {
        int tmp = x;
        x = -y;
        y = -tmp;
    }
}
```

If you want the `flip()` method to return a new point with the coordinates flipped, then you can do this:

```
public class Point {
    private int x;
    private int y;

    public Point(int x, int y) {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
    }

    public Point flip() {
        return new Point(-y, -x);
    }
}
```

Comment: One question: Why does simply doing x=-y and y=-x not work? Why do you have to set another variable equal to x first and then do the negative of that new variable? It works, thanks.

Comment: @user3211857 - If you set `x = -y`, then you've just lost the value of `x`. Then when you do `y = -x`, you'd end up storing the original value of `y` back in `y`.

Comment: Oh, of course. Somehow that logic escaped my mind for some reason. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
public Point flip(Point orig){
    return new Point(-orig.y, -orig.x);
}
```

If you can not pass it any parameters, make them class variables.

```
private Point mPoint;

public void flip(){
    mPoint.x = -mPoint.y;
    mPoint.y = -mPoint.x;
}
```

Comment: That's a flip about an arbitrary line, y = -x

Comment: OP's code does both an inversion, and flip. As did I. I think....

Comment: Your second approach will not work. You need to use a temporary variable to store `mPoint.x`; otherwise the original value is lost as soon as you do `mPoint.x = -mPoint.y;`.

Answer (score 0):

Something like the following code would work in your situation:

```
public Point flip(Point point)
{
  return new Point(-point.getY(), -point.getX());
}
```